# PHPExcel ZipArchive not found

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've just downloaded PHPExcel package and I tried to import an Excel spreadsheet, but all I get is an error `ZipArchive not found`. I work on Windows, but server is on Linux. I checked `php.ini` to see if php_zip is disabled, but it wasn't even there.

I tried  installing it with PECL: `$ pecl install zip`

`No releases availble for package "pecl.php.net/zip"
Cannot initialize 'channel://pecl.php.net/zip', invalid or missing package file
Package "channel://pecl.php.net/zip" is not valid
install failed`

And also `pear install zip-1.10.2.tgz` but recieved pretty much the same message.

I don't have root permission to the server, maybe that's the case? Anyways, could you help me with this?

Comment: I think Mark Baker may help you, what version of PHPExcel are you using? lastest release?

Comment: Yep, I use PHPExcel 1.8.0

Comment: You're apparently not the first who got this error: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/233977 . However, from what I'm reading, you also need **permissions**: http://prntscr.com/4adzsp . Have you got all the extensions required enabled? can you change permissions to PHPExcel's folder?

Comment: I don't even have php_zip line in php.ini file and adding it by myself... well... surprisingly did not work. I have permission to PHPExcel folder, but PHP requires ZipArchive installed and I can't figure out how to install it.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? In the requirements, it is said that you need at least the php version 5.2 . I suppose that if the php_zip line was not present in your PHP.ini, then I suspect that the extension is not present at all (and it would explain why it is not working). Perhaps try using a different version of PHP excel, maybe an older one...

Comment: I have PHP 5.2.5. I think I would need to recompile PHP with php_zip, but I can't do this ATM because I don't have permissions...

Comment: Then you may add and compile the ziparchive extention, or perhaps, as I said above, use an older version of PHPExcel. I'm personally using PHPExcel 1.7.6 and php 5.0; in my PHP.ini file I don't have aswell the php_zip line and everything is working.. Perhaps try using 1.7.6 for instance? https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/45412

Comment: Wait, I just saw this: http://prntscr.com/4ae5jk and also this: http://prntscr.com/4ae5oq . Try, when you include PHPExcel, to do this: `PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);`. It seems that this is related to Excel2007. I probably had no issues yet because I was NOT using any Excel2007 worksheets but just Excel2003 worksheets..

Comment: I included `PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);` before and it didn't work. But PHPExcel 1.7.6 seems to be working, at least it doesn't display `ZipArchive not found` anymore. So thanks `briosheje` for your help!!!

Comment: So, perhaps, you don't have both extensions (PCLZIP and ZipArchive). I don't think you can get any further without these extention, but I would suggest you to directly contact Mark Baker here in stackoverflow, as he is one of the developpers of phpexcel :). Edit: Oh, okay, then try working with it, perhaps it will work, but I would suggest you in any case to contact mark baker for such a case, perhaps he has the solution for such issue :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Certain spreadsheet file formats, such as OfficeOpenXML used as the default format by Excel 2007 and above, require ZipArchive. In most recent versions of PHP, ZipArchive is always available, but prior to PHP 5.3 it needed to be manually installed as a PHP extension.

As @briosheje says If you don't have ZipArchive installed/enabled for your PHP, then you can use

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

PCLZip is included in the PHPExcel distribution as an alternative to PHP's built-in ZipArchive class, though it is quite a bit slower. Enabling PCLZip allows you to work with zip-based spreadsheet formats even without ZipArchive.

However, when we first bundled PCLZip (originally in PHPExcel 1.7.6), it was only an option when writing zip-based formats, not when reading them. We changed that in PHPExcel 1.8.0, so enabling PCLZip now allows you to read zip-based formats as well as writing them.

The PHPEXcel Reader documentation details the different spreadsheet formats, and explains which ones are zip-based.

Comment: I have `PHP 7.0.8` on server and `PHP 5.5.9` on localhost with version `1.8.0` for PHPExcel on both. Everything works perfect on `localhost` but not on our server. Initially I was getting `Class  'ZipArchive' not found in Reader/Excel2007.php:94`error. So I included `PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::ZIPARCHIVE);`. But then I am getting `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive::statName() in Reader/OOCalc.php:89`. I also tried installing 'zip' module by `pecl install zip`. But it is also not working. Can you provide some pointers?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` worked for me after all these steps...

Comment: @Chaitanya solution is working for me on php 7 - Ubuntu 16.04. The accepted answer was working up to php 5.6 on Debian Jessie.

Comment: For sake of completeness, It also could be a conflict with older PHP installation. For example once I tried by removing PHP5 installation and reinstalling PHP7 version and everything worked fine

Comment: This made my day. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In my case I have PHP 5.4
Upon using PHPExcel, I encountered this exception.

```
FatalErrorException in Excel2007.php line 94: Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

Solved it by appending this line on **PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php**

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

before invoking the getZipClass method.

```
$zipClass = PHPExcel_Settings::getZipClass();
```

Comment: not worked. When i include this line. it gives error in the line 317 in the same file.

Comment: got this error while writing file, so added this to PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php at line 220. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You have to install extension for php called like **php-zip** and zip program on your linux machine.

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple solution:

1. login to your cpanel
2. go to software > select PHP version
3. select PHP version 7.0 and click set as current button
4. check zip checkbox
5. click save

Now you refresh your site to download excel file

Answer (score 4):

If you are using cpanel you may have zip extension installed but not activate. You need to active it. For this case you need to go to cpanel > inside software section > click on PHP version. Then find zip and check it. Now save.
[image: Enable zip extension]

Refresh your application page.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to insert : 

    `PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);`

in your script just before  calling  `$objWriter->save();`

This worked for me.

regards!

Comment: That is [what Mark Baker answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25181889/479156) more than four years ago. Is this intended as an actual answer, or just a confirmation that it works? And if it is meant as an answer, please explain what additional value it has over Mark's answer. If it doesn't have any, please consider deleting it as it serves no additional value.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this one worked

```
sudo apt install php7.1-zip
```