# Class 'ZipArchive' not found error while using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-5.2

When I use PHPExcel on a new server,
I faced the error "Class 'ZipArchive' not found" and it seems to be blocked by my hosting service provider.

Can't I use PHPExcel on the server without Zip support? 
PHP 5.2.8 is installed on this server but I can't use a basic PHP source code for PHPExcel.

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/class.ziparchive.php) should be present on a 5.2.8 system. Anyway, 5.2 is [no longer supported](http://php.net/eol.php). You should move to a better host

Comment: If you're only using PHP 5.2.8, then I'd strongly recommend that you kick your hosting provider with hobnail boots until they upgrade your PHP to a version that is still under active support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel ZipArchive not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176999/phpexcel-ziparchive-not-found)

Answer (score 8):

Certain spreadsheet file formats, such as OfficeOpenXML used as the default format by Excel 2007 and above, require ZipArchive. In most recent versions of PHP, ZipArchive is always available, but prior to PHP 5.3 it needed to be manually installed on some systems as a PHP extension.

If you don't have ZipArchive installed/enabled for your PHP, and can't enable it yourself, then you can use

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

PCLZip is included in the PHPExcel distribution as an alternative to PHP's built-in ZipArchive class, though it is quite a bit slower. Enabling PCLZip allows you to work with zip-based spreadsheet formats even without ZipArchive.

However, when we first bundled PCLZip (originally in PHPExcel 1.7.6), it was only an option when writing zip-based formats, not when reading them. We changed that in PHPExcel 1.8.0, so enabling PCLZip now allows you to read zip-based formats as well as writing them.

The PHPEXcel Reader documentation details the different spreadsheet formats, and explains which ones are zip-based. 
[PHPEXcel Reader documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files)

Comment: Really? The doco says it's in PHP 5 >= 5.2.0

Comment: Irrespective of what the docs say, there were certainly issues with its availability on Windows platforms in earlier versions than 5.3.0, and I believe it had to be configured for a Linux build as well.... I've had to deal with a lot of people having problems with ZipArchive not being available, which is why I had to introduce the PCLZip alternative

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me to understand what's wrong. Can we have an example how to use PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP); ?

Comment: [01simplePCLZip.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simplePCLZip.php)

Comment: ran into this on an Ubuntu 16 installation with php7 - sorted it with `apt-get install php7.0-zip`