# How to enable ZipArchive in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, excel

I have successfully implemented uploading Excel files to my database using phpexcel library. It's working perfectly on localhost but when tested in live server I got this error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /xxxx/PHPExcel-develop/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php .
```

I have found a solution on this question: [PHPExcel ZipArchive not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176999/phpexcel-ziparchive-not-found) but it's not helping me.

I know ZIP extention has to enabled using this line of code

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

But I don't know where to use this code in the excel library. Also I don't have direct access to root server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

right after the line

```
require_once 'path/to/PHPExcel.php';
```

or before any instanciation of the PHPExcel class.

Comment: i dont have server acces. Then how will i enable this in server

Comment: Unless you find a way to modify your PHP configuration on your hosting, you won't be able to enable the extension.

Comment: have you ever modified your PHP configuration on host

Comment: Some hosting companies provides a way to alter your php.ini, you might want to contact yours to see what is possible.

Comment: Did you refer the question i linked?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully read the linked question. Seems like I missed some informations.

Comment: Here is the error i am getting`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive::statName() in /home/gksfapp/public_html/backend/admin_panel/PHPExcel-develop/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/OOCalc.php `

Comment: Which version of PHPExcel are you using ? The last one doesn't use `statname()` in OOCalc.php.

Comment: I don't know can you give the link of latest

Comment: phpexcel version 1.8.0

Comment: From what I am reading from the sources, PCLZip is not supported in 1.8.0, or the author didn't upgrade the class `PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive` with the last functions needed to work. I suggest either enabling php_zip extension or contacting the author so that he can update the file and provide a patch.

Comment: Is  there is no another way?

Comment: You can always try to download the previous version (1.7.x) and see if it works better for your needs. It may need to make some modifications of your code to work in the same way.

Comment: @BlessanKurien: I am also facing exact issue...How did you resolve this issue?