# Laravel export is not working on server, But working fine on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

following is the code which I used for export functionality

```
public function export(){
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('user_type','Farmer')->orWhere('user_type','Dealer')->select('id','name','middlename','surname','mobile','state','district','taluka','user_type')->get()->map(function ($item, $key){
            return (array) $item;
        })
        ->all();

        $usersArray = []; 
        foreach ($users as $user) {
             $usersArray[] =$user;
        }


        Excel::create('users',function($excel)use($usersArray) {
            $excel->setTitle('users');
            $excel->setCreator('Laravel');
            $excel->setDescription('users file');
            $excel->sheet('sheet1',function($sheet)use($usersArray) {
            $sheet->fromArray($usersArray,null,'A1',true,true);
            });

        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

This code is working fine on localhost,no issue at localhost, But on server it is showing error that "This site can't be reached", I am unable to figure it out that what is the issue on server. 
I even try some other solutions on stackoverflow but unable to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHPExcel ZipArchive not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176999/phpexcel-ziparchive-not-found/41627136#41627136) after lot of trouble finally this solution is worked for me. I just append PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP); this line before $zipClass = PHPExcel_Settings::getZipClass(); In File PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php, and Now my export function is running on server too.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $users = DB::table('users')
               ->where('user_type','Farmer')
               ->orWhere('user_type','Dealer')
               ->select('id', 'name', 'middlename', 'surname', 'mobile', 'state', 'district', 'taluka','user_type')
               ->get()->map(function ($item, $key){
                    return (array) $item;
               })->all()->toArray();
```

After using `->toArray()`, the variable `$users` variable will be an array

Now coming to your point,

Possibilites of Error

1) Folder permission to create a temp file

2) Allowed memory size exceeded, you can change the memory size to unlimited in `php.ini` file or in your code by setting `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');`

3) Give write permission to the storage directory of laravel setup in the server.

4) check the apache/nginx log for some other possibilities of error, as it is a 500 error response it should be logged into the log file of apache/nginx.

My suggestion is to use `league/csv` packages or `box/spout` packages with laravel Excel related works.

Comment: I directly used box/spout and it is working fine on both localhost as well as on server, Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happened yesterday, by mistake I make testing both the time on localhost and I thought that it was working on server now and even I mark that answer active..
1.Created php.ini file on server....
2.set memory limit to -1, i.e. 128M from 64M
3.set wite permission to storage folder
But export is still not working...

Comment: restarted apache in server ?

Comment: Yes I checked after restaring apache but still unable to work...When I ceck log , I get this log error: production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'ZipArchive' not found'

Comment: I search solution for this and try to update php to 7.0 But we are having shared server so unable to update php version to 7.0

Comment: as you are getting Class 'ZipArchive' not found, it seems PHP needs to have the zip extension installed. here is the link, check for the php version and install the zip extension for that version

http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41627136/6708612    ..after lot of trouble finally this solution is worked for me.
I just append PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);  this line before $zipClass = PHPExcel_Settings::getZipClass(); In File PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php, and Now my export function is running on server too.

Comment: @Nil Oh Okay , you are forcing to choose the default ZipClass from the package ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, you don't have to make `$usersArray` by own, just use `toArray()` method after `all()`.

Is there any message in your nginx/apache log?